# Doesn't pop to Parent view from the Child view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I have 3 view controllers "Root", "Parent" & "Child". Now i am pushing into Child from a method of Parent. Now when i want to pop to parent from the Child view through the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
Parent *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Parent"];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

This shows the error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
```

When i write the following code instead, It pop to a blank screen! :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And when I write the following code, It pop to Root. :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But I want to pop to Parent view exactly. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance.

Push example from class Parent:

```
-(void)Custom{

if([info isEqualToString:@"message"]){

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];

Child *cd = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Child"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:cd animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Pop example from Child:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

 [super viewDidLoad];

 [self sendMessage]

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
Parent *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Parent"];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:svc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can't pop to the Child view controller because is not added to the navigation controller stack. (You make a new instance of Child when you call `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Child"];`)

If you push Parent and after that you push the child form the Parent, and if you call from the Child `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` it should work.

Comment: Sorry i wrote some wrong example in the question. I have edited that. please check now.

Comment: My answer is stil valid, but can you add the code where you are pushing and popping the view controllers ?

Comment: I have added the code of pushing & popping in the question section. Please check now.

Comment: You should't pop the view controller in `-(void)viewDidLoad`. Try to pop the view controller when tapping on a button from Child view controller and use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`;

Answer (score 0):

For popping up your view controller, you can use the following code...

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for( int i=0;i<[ viewContrlls count];i++){
            id obj=[viewContrlls objectAtIndex:i];
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[<yourViewController> class]] ){

                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps you..:)